# How do I avoid my array crashing in HTML Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started to learn how to code in the last few weeks. I am currently trying to tackle Javascript within HTML, and I have made what is a basic savings vs loan calculator. However, every time I run it, it crashes. I think it is because I have used an array, rather than an object. When I tried to convert it to an object, I got a bit list and couldn't get the code to run at all.

Here is what I have made in terms of HTML:

```
    <div class="main">
        <p><b>Try me...</b></p>
        <div class="inputs">
        <p>How much do you currently have saved? <input type="number" id="istart" min="0"><br>
            How much are you saving every month? <input type="number" id="ichange" min="0"><br>
            Do you have a final payment on your loan? (if none, leave blank) <input type="number" id="iend" min="0"><br>
            How much do you have left to pay on your loan? <input type="number" id="qstart" min="0"> <br>
            How much are you paying monthly? <input type="number" id="qchange" min="0"></p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" onclick="myCalculation()">Tell me!</button>

        <p id="calc"></p>
        <p>Number of months to save:</p>
        <p id="length"></p>
        <p id="calc1"></p> 
        <p>Number of months to pay:</p>
        <p id="length1"></p>


        <p><b>How many months do you have left?</b></p> 
        <p>After <input type="number" id="arrayselector" min="1" max="28"> month(s), you have saved £ <b id="one"></b> with £ <b id="A"></b> to go on the payments!</p>
        <button type="button" onclick="myMonths()">How many?</button>
        <script src="calculator.js"></script> 
    </div>
```

And here is the accompanying .js file:

```
   function myCalculation() { 


             var istart = document.getElementById("istart").value;
             var iend = document.getElementById("iend").value;

             if (iend === "") {
                 var iend = 999999;
             }

             var qstart = document.getElementById("qstart").value; 
             //var qend = 6000;

             var ichange = document.getElementById("ichange").value;
             var qchange = document.getElementById("qchange").value; 

             var arr = [];
             var arr1 = []; 

             while(istart < iend) {
                 arr.push(istart+=ichange);
             }
             while(qstart > iend) {
                 arr1.push(qstart-=qchange);
             }


             document.getElementById("length").innerHTML = arr.length; 
             document.getElementById("length1").innerHTML = arr1.length;
         }

    function myMonths() {

var istart = document.getElementById("istart").value;
             var iend = document.getElementById("iend").value;

             if (iend === "") {
                 var iend = 999999;
             }

             var qstart = document.getElementById("qstart").value; 
             //var qend = 6000;

             var ichange = document.getElementById("ichange").value;
             var qchange = document.getElementById("qchange").value; 

             var arr = [];
             var arr1 = []; 

             while(istart < iend) {
                 arr.push(istart+=ichange);
             }
             while(qstart > iend) {
                 arr1.push(qstart-=qchange);
             }


            var input = document.getElementById('arrayselector').value;

             document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = arr[input];
             document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = arr1[input]; 

}
```

Apologies if this is really, really terrible code, but I have just started and I am learning entirely through these forums, W3school, and Codecademy. So far, I have got most things to work as I hoped but I just can't get this to run without crashing. Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the error you're getting?

Comment: `value`s from input elements are always strings. You might get unexpected results when comparing strings with `<` or `>`. Convert those values to numbers before using  them in `while` conditions.

Comment: @jianweichuah when I try to run the code in Chrome, it just crashes the browser.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks for the advice, what the best way to go about turning a string to a number value?

Comment: @TobySBevan That's purely something you should search for on your own. Internet is full of good examples and tutorials about the subject. One of the most useful sites you'd ever find, is [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide)

Comment: @teemu you're right. I did look it up, and I put in code to change it from string to numbers. It no longer crashes, but it also no longer outputs. That link is super helpful, and I shall continue to try make it work! Thanks!